# Как следует проверять (экранировать) введённые пользователем $email и $message перед отправкой функцией mail()?

Tags: php

Как следует проверять (экранировать) введённые пользователем $email и $message перед отправкой функцией mail()?

```
$headers = 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" . 'From: ' . $email;
mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Subject', $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можете использовать [такой](https://github.com/zf1/zend-mail/blob/24c8847df94836006c1e0f2dd4209dd46fa11bf1/library/Zend/Mail.php#L1205) подход.

```
function _filterEmail($email)
{
    $rule = array("\r" => '',
                  "\n" => '',
                  "\t" => '',
                  '"'  => '',
                  ','  => '',
                  '<'  => '',
                  '>'  => '',
    );
    return strtr($email, $rule);
}

function _filterOther($data)
{
    $rule = array("\r" => '',
                  "\n" => '',
                  "\t" => '',
    );
    return strtr($data, $rule);
}

$email   = _filterEmail($email);
$message = _filterOther($message);

mail(...);
```

Comment: Я так понял что нужно просто '\r\n' из $email вырезать чтобы не было инклюда лишних заголовков. А вот в $message '\r\n' допустимо.

Answer (score 0):

Для фильтрации мыла легко подходит [встроенная функция:](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-var.php)

`$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);`

Тело, на сколько я понимаю данный пример допустимо не фильтровать.